# Pasting an import statement in front of a thunk using macros

Tags: scala, macros

Triggered by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18535356/multiple-late-initialisation), I was wondering if one could write a def-macro to achieve the result:

```
import scala.reflect.macros.Context
import language.experimental.macros

object CarImpl {
  def impl(c: Context)(fun: c.Expr[Unit]): c.Expr[Unit] = {
    import c.universe._
    val all  = "_": TermName
    val imp  = c.Expr(Import(c.prefix.tree, ImportSelector(all, -1, all, -1) :: Nil))
    val tree = reify {
      imp.splice
      fun.splice
    } .tree
    c.Expr(tree)
  }
}
class Car(var speed: Int, var color: String) {
  def set(fun: Unit): Unit = macro CarImpl.impl
}
```

Application:

```
val myCar = new Car(5, "red")
myCar.set { color = "blue" }
```

This fails to compile because: `not found: value color`. It seems its not enough to "paste" the import statement in front of it. Any clues if the general idea can be realised? That is, the following should be the synthetic output

```
val myCar = new Car(5, "red")

{
  import myCar._
  color = "blue"
}
```

Comment: Would you settle for something like `set { 'color -> "blue" }`? Because that's definitely possible, and not too hard. You could get the `set { color = "blue" }` syntax with some cleverness with structural types and an extra import (one for every class), but it would be messy.

Comment: No, what I would really like is pass the function body as is into the macro body, before the compiler tries to resolve symbols, I guess... You know, you could write `Button { text = "foo"; enabled = false }` instead of `new Button { ... }`.

Comment: You'd need untyped macros for that, unfortunately, and they're now [off the table](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/untypedmacros.html).

Comment: Ok, thanks. I can see that they are not an "essential" feature without which one couldn't live. I was just curious. I still hate the `new` keyword :)

Comment: I've just written up [a blog post](http://meta.plasm.us/posts/2013/08/30/horrible-code/) with a kind of solution to this problem.

Comment: It's cool that one can upvote comments as well :)

Comment: @TravisBrown Since you address the question, you should paste that blog link into an answer, and I'm willing to close that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to get this syntax, but it takes a kind of crazy trick involving structural types (and requires one extra line of boilerplate). I've written [a blog post](http://meta.plasm.us/posts/2013/08/30/horrible-code/) discussing the trick in detail, and will give a simplified version here.

First for the macro implementation for `set` (note that I'm using quasiquotes, which are now available as a plugin in 2.10):

```
import scala.reflect.macros.Context
import scala.language.experimental.macros

trait SetterBuilder {
  def set_impl(c: Context)(assignments: c.Expr[Unit]): c.Expr[Unit] = {
    import c.universe._

     val rewriteOne: PartialFunction[Tree, Tree] = {
       case q"${_}.$n($v)" => q"${c.prefix}.$n($v)"
     }

     val rewrite: PartialFunction[Tree, Tree] = rewriteOne orElse {
       case block: Block => q"{ ..${block collect rewriteOne} }"
     }

     c.Expr(
       rewrite.lift(assignments.tree).getOrElse(
         c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, "Not a set of assignments!")
       )
     )
  }
}
```

And then the structural type stuff:

```
trait SyntaxBuilder {
  def syntax_impl[A: c.WeakTypeTag](c: Context) = {
    import c.universe._

    val anon = newTypeName(c.fresh())
    val declarations = c.weakTypeOf[A].declarations

    val (getters, setters) = declarations.collect {
      case sym: MethodSymbol if sym.isSetter => (
        q"def ${sym.getter.name} = ???",
        q"def ${sym.name}(x: ${sym.paramss.head.head.typeSignature}) = ???"
      )
    }.unzip

    c.Expr[Any](q"class $anon { ..$getters; ..$setters }; new $anon {}")
  }
}
```

Now we tie it all together and define our class:

```
object Evil extends SyntaxBuilder with SetterBuilder {
  def syntax[A] = macro syntax_impl[A]
}

case class Car(var speed: Int, var color: String) {
  def set(assignments: Unit): Unit = macro Evil.set_impl
}

object Car {
  val syntax = Evil.syntax[Car]
}
```

We get the boilerplate out of the way:

```
import Car.syntax._
```

And we're done:

```
scala> val car = new Car(0, "blue")
car: Car = Car(0,blue)

scala> car set {
     |   color = "red"
     |   speed = 10000
     | }

scala> car
res0: Car = Car(10000,red)
```

See [the blog post](http://meta.plasm.us/posts/2013/08/30/horrible-code/) for a more fully-featured version, an explanation, and an apology for introducing this awful code into the world.

Comment: Plugging the plug: in M5, use q"$_" instead of q"${_}" to save your eyesight.

Comment: @som-snytt: If _that_'s the part that hurts your eyes, I envy you.